ng build hang because it tries to connect to socket io?
I'm on Angular 17.3.7 and I'm using it with ngx-socket-io 4.6.1. I'm making a SocketService to communicate with my FastApi backend server. The static files are served by the FastApi framework and for that I need to run "ng build".
My issue is with the latest. When I run the build command it hangs indefinitely. I have no error or whatsoever and the worst in that is that I can see the "connected" event on my backend from the angular frontend while he is doing the "ng build".
If I use the "autoconnect: False" I can build with no issues which make me think that the error is linked to the connection. I don't really understand what is happening and I would really appreciate some help.
Here is the socket.service.ts:
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Socket } from 'ngx-socket-io';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class SocketService {
  constructor(private socket: Socket) {}

  listen(eventName: string): Observable<any> {
    return this.socket.fromEvent(eventName);
  }

  emit(eventName: string, data: any): void {
    this.socket.emit(eventName, data);
  }
}

here is how I use it:
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {
      allConnected: boolean = false;

      constructor(
        private socketService: SocketService
      ) { }
    
      ngOnInit() {

          this.socketService.listen('all_connected').subscribe((data: any) => {
            if (data.all_connected) {
              this.allConnected = true;
            }
          });
    
        });
      }

Last but not least the app.config.ts:
import { ApplicationConfig, importProvidersFrom } from '@angular/core';
import { provideRouter } from '@angular/router';

import { routes } from './app.routes';
import { provideClientHydration } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { provideAnimationsAsync } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations/async';
import { provideHttpClient, withFetch } from '@angular/common/http';
import { SocketIoModule, SocketIoConfig } from 'ngx-socket-io';

const config: SocketIoConfig = { url: 'http://localhost:3000', options: {} };

export const appConfig: ApplicationConfig = {
  providers: [provideRouter(routes), provideClientHydration(), provideAnimationsAsync(), provideHttpClient(withFetch()),
    importProvidersFrom(SocketIoModule.forRoot(config))
  ],
};

